# Change Index range by Cell value

Tags: vba, excel

If I put the correct range somewhere on the spreadsheet, IE cell

> NAME_INPUT!B73

How can I use that range listed there:

> A78:AJ118

as the range to replace A82:AJ117 in this formula

> =ROUND(INDEX('QB IS by class'!A82:AJ117,MATCH("4010 · Billing",'QB IS by class'!F1:F38,0),MATCH("-Billing",'QB IS by class'!1:1,0))/1000,0)

So the final result would be:

> =ROUND(INDEX('QB IS by class'!A78:AJ118,MATCH("4010 · Billing",'QB IS by class'!F1:F38,0),MATCH("-Billing",'QB IS by class'!1:1,0))/1000,0)

And I'd only have to change that cell on sheet NAME_INPUT to change every formula referencing to this range.

Thanks guys

Comment: The Second MATCH is only looking in 38 Cells, It would also need to be increased to match the number of rows or the last 3 will never be returned.  and if the range is less then it may error.

Comment: @ScottCraner The range the second match is looking for never changes. It's the header columns, and they're frozen

Comment: Sorry I meant the first MATCH.  It currently will return a number between 1 and 38, while you have 41 rows in the return range.  39,40 and 41 will never be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but I think you are looking for the INDIRECT function.
Replace `'QB IS by class'!A78:AJ118` with `INDIRECT("'QB IS by class'!" & NAME_INPUT!B73)`

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed, I just didn't know how to Google it, lol. Thank you!